# How to get comments of youtube Video from VideoId android in youtubeApi v3?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I've taken a look at [Youtube Api v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) for Android and I can get most of information about `Youtube Video` via `Video Id`. However, after of searching a lot in google, it seems no way to get `comments` of `Youtube Video` with Api v3. I tried this [Video.List Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) a lot, but I found nothing about comments. So, I want to ask for a guide to retrieve my goal. Can any one help me, or give me any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: i don't know how to getting comments youtube Api(v3) . but one of the way is getting comments on video id. u just try this api direct to call.http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/DBNYwxDZ_pA/comments?orderby=published&alt=json&max-results=30&start-index=1  and change the ur video id.its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I made a research on Youtube API and came across some important API changes on commenting system.

As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments#Retrieve_comments), Youtube API v3 has a new commenting system. You should check out the IMPORTANT section at the top of the page. Also you should look at this [Upcoming changes page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments).

But their 'New commenting system' page is not working right now. Maybe you can check out later. If you just want to retrieve comments for a specific video, you can do it with API v3. But if you want to create new comments too, you should use API v2 for now.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I want to retrieve comments only, so how to do it with Api v3? Can you explain it more detail?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get comments using the YouTube Data API **v3** because comments isn't part of v3 yet.

To retrieve comments you have to use the YouTube Data API **v2**. To quote Google:

> While the new comments aren’t currently supported in the YouTube Data API v3, you can continue to use the older version of the API (v2) with a few caveats outlined below (and the benefits covered above). [2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments?hl=nl)

[How to retrieve comments using v2 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments?hl=nl#Retrieve_comments)

[More info about changes made in comment system.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments?hl=nl)