# Accessing comments of a video

Tags: youtube-api

I'm having trouble finding a way to access comments from a youtube video.
The closest thing I came across told me that that feature was a google+ only api call.
using
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#try-it
i get

- SHOW HEADERS -
  {
   "error": {
  "errors": [
     {
  "domain": "youtube.comment",
  "reason": "operationNotSupported",
  "message": "The id filter is only compatible with comments based on  Google+.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "id"
   }
  ],
   "code": 400,
  "message": "The id filter is only compatible with comments based on Google+."
  }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CommentThreads:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) which returns a list of all comments threads that match the API request parameters.

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads
```

If the response is successfull, method returns a response body with the following structure:

```
{
"kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
"etag": etag,
"nextPageToken": string,
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": integer,
"resultsPerPage": integer
},
"items": [
commentThread Resource
]
}
```

Here's a YouTube API sample code with different supported programming languages: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#examples

Found this Stack Overflow related ticket, discuss how to get comments through YouTube API: [How to get comments through Youtube Data API v3 / JSOUP parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646598/how-to-get-comments-through-youtube-data-api-v3-jsoup-parsing)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, It's almost working but I'm finding a few issues with this. First the items look like this 
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/lwxPlgLWRyYfudZ5EW4zKFdXwgk\"",
   "id": "z13hxfupbxfqxzwnw23mjzgoftbzczfjr04"
  },
  {
etc.. 
And I don't know how to get the actual comment (text) from it.
Second it's limited to a max of 100 comment, but I want to get all comments of the video.

Comment: First problem solved, now how do I retrieve all comments from the video without the 100 cap ?